# SQL ORDER BY CSV input parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have sample table and query with the issue described here,

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    NAME VARCHAR(250),
    VALUE float 
) 

INSERT INTO test(NAME,[VALUE])VALUES('A',100)
INSERT INTO test(NAME,[VALUE])VALUES('B',200)
INSERT INTO test(NAME,[VALUE])VALUES('C',200)

SELECT * FROM test WHERE ID IN (2,1,3) 

ID          NAME      VALUE
----------- --------- ----------------
1           A         100
2           B         200
3           C         200
```

QUERY : when I pass **(2,1,3)** in WHERE clause it should give result in same ORDER as below :

```
ID          NAME      VALUE
----------- --------- ----------------
2           B         200
1           A         100
3           C         200
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: It won't. It checks for each row that it belongs to the set defined in the `IN` clause, but it will produce the resultset as it gets the rows

Comment: your question is database depending  so please tell us which db you are using

Comment: Using SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you grab a copy of [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) you could do this:

```
-- assuming these values come in as a parameter:
DECLARE @searchString varchar(100) = '2,1,3';

-- solution using delimitedSplit8K
SELECT t.ID, t.Name, t.VALUE 
FROM dbo.test t
JOIN dbo.delimitedSplit8K(@searchString,',') s ON s.item = t.id
ORDER BY s.itemNumber;
```

Results:

```
ID          Name  VALUE 
----------- ----- ------
2           B     200
1           A     100
3           C     200
```

What makes this technique particularly wonderful is how, if you examine the query execution plan, there is no Sort Operator.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why you would *expect* the results to be in the order of the `in` list.  SQL works with *unordered sets*; so there is no intrinsic ordering -- unless it is explicitly done with an `order by` clause.

It looks like you are using SQL Server.  You can do what you want with a `join`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test t JOIN
     (VALUES (2, 1), (1, 2), (3, 3)
     ) v(id, ordering)
     ON t.id = v.id
ORDER BY ordering;
```